# Possibility of Storing the Output of Step in Github Action

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to figure out if there is a way in GitHub Actions where we can save the output of a step in its entirety, i.e whatever was displayed on the GitHub console, can be stored or saved in a way so that I can be redirected into a file or something.

Here is a snapshot, where a plugin displayed a verbose output, I would like to store or pass on this info in a file for further use:

[image]

I think this might even be called logs.

Could not figure it out anyway until yet.

Answer (score 2):

If we only focus on the [aquasecurity/trivy-action](https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy-action) here (which seems to be the logs in question) then it already provides a configuration option `output` to specify an output file to store its output.

According to its [inputs](https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy-action#inputs), you can use `output`:

> `output` | Save results to a file

and, also configure a `format` according to your requirements (default: `table`):

> `format` | Output format (`table`, `json`, `sarif`, `github`)

With `format: json`, you can then use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for easy manipulation.

---

Apart from that, to get the logs, you can use the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) i.e. `gh run view`.

See [Viewing logs with GitHub CLI](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/using-workflow-run-logs#viewing-logs-with-github-cli) and [About GitHub CLI](https://docs.github.com/en/github-cli/github-cli/about-github-cli) for more details.

You can also use the GitHub API. See [Download workflow run attempt logs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#download-workflow-run-attempt-logs).